# kprobes, backtrace, same symbol adjacent to itself

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand the output from the backtrace I captured using kprobes.  If you'd like to see the full stack trace, that's fine, but it's not necessary for the question.  Below is an excerpt:

```
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff813a2b2e>] ? ata_scsi_port_error_handler+0x4be/0x710
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff813a2ea8>] ? ata_scsi_cmd_error_handler+0x128/0x180
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff813a2f98>] ? ata_scsi_error+0x98/0xd0
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff81386cfa>] ? scsi_error_handler+0x12a/0x810
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff81386bd0>] ? scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x810
Jul 24 16:31:34 scilinx kernel: [<ffffffff8109aef6>] ? kthread+0x96/0xa0
```

You'll notice that `scsi_error_handler` is adjacent to itself in the call stack but I cannot find why this is.  Here is the  [scsi_error_handler function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_error.c?v=2.6.32#L1674) for this kernel.  As you can see, it does not call itself.  So why does the stacktrace show it adjacent to itself like this?

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax is: <funcname>+offset-into-func/size-of-func. 
So you've got two call frames to the same function, however at differing offsets (the first at 0x0, second at 0x12a bytes). 
Of course, am not certain of this, but possibly: (a) a kprobe can be set at an offset _inside_ a function (can be specified). (b) a function can be reentered from another context (like a kernel thread). Yes, I agree, it does not usually show like this in a call chain though..

Comment: @kaiwan Thanks for the info about what the syntax is.  I was wondering about the 0x810 shown for scsi_error_handler.  Your other comments are insightful too.  If the kprobe works as I understand it to, i.e. I set a *pre-* handler then the second listing of scsi_error_handler shouldn't be the kprobe but possibly a re-entrant thread.